# flot: Show units on axes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

In flot, is there any way I can get the axes to show $10, $20 etc, rather than just 10, 20?

I've checked [the documentation](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) but don't see a way, but it seems like to be a common requirement - especially since you can't (easily) label the axes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking for the "tickFormatter" option in the [API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt).

For example:

```
var data1 = [[0,3],[10,1],[20,2],[40,8],[50,10]];

someFunc = function(val, axis){
   return "$" + val
}

plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
    [{ data: data1}], {
      xaxis: { tickFormatter: someFunc }
    });
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking if there is possible to show only one unit name for xaxis. thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang, I'm not sure what you mean.  You could add an axis label underneath that said `(in dollars)` or something

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I mean , Let's say in your sample, show `$` besides the max value of xaxis which is `$50` not for every values. Now, I already knew how to make it based on your answer. Thanks.